# Getting error - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm

I am working with log-in activity in pycharm with database MySQL and using library flask.
While checking email and password I am getting an error: "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable."

The error is as follows:

```
File "C:\Users\Ganesh kadam\PycharmProjects\myproject\main.py", line 26, in index 
 if info['email']==username and info['password']==password: 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect,session, url_for
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "1234353234"

app.config["MYSQL_HOST"] = "local"
app.config["MYSQL_USER"] = "root"
app.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] = "password"
app.config["MYSQL_DB"] = "login"

db = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
            username = request.form['username']
            password = request.form['password']
            cursor = db.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `logininfo` WHERE 'email'=%s AND 'password'=%s", (username, password))
            info = cursor.fetchone()
            print(info)
            if info['email']==username and info['password']==password:
                return "Logged in Successfully"
            else:
                return "Please register first!"
    return render_template("login.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Please post the full detail of the error you are getting.

Comment: File "C:\Users\Ganesh kadam\PycharmProjects\myproject\main.py", line 26, in index
if info['email']==username and info['password']==password:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: The code in that error message does not match the code you have posted.

Comment: if info['email']==username and info['password']==password:

Comment: Please don't selectively edit your error message to pretend it came from your code. `info['email']` and `info('email')` are different things and would not generate the same error message.

Comment: I am not pretending, I have tried with -  info('email') also and by mistake I have copied older text from old error, So now I have corrected text from error.

Comment: So Following is error -TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable,                           if info['email']==username and info['password']==password:

Comment: OK, that's actually possible. Your question says it's getting different error, which is not possible. "'NoneType' object is not callable" is different from "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: ok Sir, Could you please give me solution?

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem in your query. You should be using backticks or nothing at all for you column names, and not  single quotes. Using  single quotes, you are testing if the string email is equal to something.
This query:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `logininfo` WHERE 'email'=%s AND 'password'=%s", (username, password))
```

Sould be like this

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `logininfo` WHERE email=%s AND password=%s", (username, password))
```

Beside that, you should test if info is empty or not (to see if any email and password matches your query or not. If info is empty you will get an error (if you don't test it)

Comment: I have tries this solution but without success and how should I check info is empty or not? What is right way to create variable and assign the value from query?

Comment: _if info['email']==username and info['password']==password_ this doesn't make sense. If you make your query with *where*, you know that for all the rows you get it will be true